# Angular List my objects in vertical alphabetical columns

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've seen a couple examples out there but I can't get it to apply to what I am doing. I know it has to be something silly I am missing.

My report objects are sorted like this by description

report { "description" }

```
a,b,c,d
 e,f,g,h
```

I want

```
a,d,g,j
b,e,h,k
c,f,i,l

<div class="row">
<div data-ng-repeat="report in reports | orderBy:['description']" >
      <div class="col-xs-3">  {{report.description}}</div>
</div>
...
```

I've tried chunking the data and several other approaches I've seen on here and I get a mix of results. Every 5th row starts anew with the above code, but my order is across (Horizontal) but I need it in 4 columns alphabetical down (Vertical) ....

It certainly can't be as hard as I am making it...

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this below logic?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
        {{convertedData}}
    </div>
    <script src="../lib/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', []);
        app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'];
            $scope.convertedData = {};
            var length = $scope.data.length;
            var rows = length / 3;
            for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++)
            {
                $scope.convertedData[j] = [];
            }
            for(var i=0;i<length;i++)
            {
                $scope.convertedData[i%3].push($scope.data[i]);
            }
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code to order your reports

```
$scope.reports = [{ description: 'a' }, { description: 'b' }, { description: 'c' }, { description: 'd' }, { description: 'e' }, { description: 'f' }, { description: 'g' }, { description: 'h' }, { description: 'i' }, { description: 'j' }, { description: 'k' }, { description: 'l' }];
$scope.orderedReports = [];

var j = 0;
var i = j;
while ($scope.reports.length > $scope.orderedReports.length) {
    $scope.orderedReports.push($scope.reports[i]);
    i = i + 3;
    if (i + 1 > $scope.reports.length) {
        j = j + 1;
        i = j;
    }
}
```

after ordering the data ng-repeat will show reports the way you want them.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="report in reports" >
      <div class="col-xs-3">  
          {{report.description}}
      </div>
</div>
```